# If columns match then

Tags: with-statement

I have looked at several examples and I am confused as to what to use.
I have 3 columns. If the data in all 3 columns(same line across) I would like it either to highlight the line or make some indicated that atleast one of the columns differ.  What is the best approach?

3550    3550    3550    true
3551    3150    3550    false

Comment: Language?  Bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way would be with a spreadsheet like Excel or Libreoffice:

- Paste your data in to Excel or similar
- In the fourth column put a function to check the value and return true or false based on whether the values match.

  E.g. if you have your values in columns A, B and C, put a function like the following in the fourth column:

  =IF(($A1=$B1)&($A1=$C1),"true","false")

Another way would be using awk if you have the data in a text file, e.g

```
$ cat data.txt
3550    3550    3550
3550    3551    3552
3550    3550    3550
$ awk '{if (($1==$2) && ($1==$3)) { print $1, $2, $3, "true" } else { print $1, $2, $3}}' data.txt 
3550 3550 3550 true
3550 3551 3552
3550 3550 3550 true
```